# Ifstream doesnt find file in subfolder

Tags: c++, file, directory

It seems like a simple problem, but I just did not manage to figure it out, even with the help of the Internet.

So basically, because my project became rather big on files, I wanted to clean up the working directory by creating subfolders. So I moved e.g. shader files to Ressources/Shaders/ .

Now I just wanted to load them in as usual with the new path, but I always get an error.

```
ifstream fin("Ressources/Shaders/texture.vs");
```

does not work. as well as

```
.\\Ressources\\Shaders\\textures.vs
./Ressources/Shaders/textures.vs
/Ressources/Shaders/textures.vs
\\Ressources\\Shaders\\textures.vs
Ressources/Shaders/textures.vs
Ressources\\Shaders\\textures.vs
```

I also tried without capital letters.
while

```
"texture.vs"
```

worked when it still was in the working directory.

I appreciate any tips.

Comment: Is `Ressources` in the working directory? And did you mean to spell it with `ss` instead of `s` (i.e. `Resources`)?

Comment: My advice: check the program execution directory.

Comment: @Cornstalks I double misspelled it so the name is right

Comment: @YSC it is set to $(ProjectDir) in Visual Studio, is that right?

Comment: @Eskalior it depends. Print it during run time and check it.

Comment: @YSC It seems to be right. It is C:\Users\XYZ\OneDrive\Projects\PROJEKT\PROJEKT\ and the location of the file is C:\Users\XYZ\OneDrive\Projekte\PROJEKT\PROJEKT\Ressources\Shaders

Comment: @Eskalior ok better safe than sorry. What's the error message? What state are the failbits of your `ifstream`are?

Comment: @YSC 0xccccccccError reading characters of string.

Comment: C:\Users\XYZ\OneDrive\Projects\PROJEKT\PROJEKT\ and C:\Users\XYZ\OneDrive\Projekte\PROJEKT\PROJEKT\ are not the same. Mispelled?

Comment: @pistachiobk yep. Translated it in one case, forgot in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can check what your current working directory is (this path must match the path of the file you are trying to open):

```
char * dir = getcwd(NULL, 0);    
cout << dir << endl;
```

Then you can check if your file exists by trying to open it (capitalization shouldn't matter):

```
ifstream fin("Ressources\\Shaders\\texture.vs");
if (fin)
    cout << "File Exists" << endl;
else 
    cout << "File Doesn't Exist" << endl;
```

If your paths are correct, this should work.

If you want to see what path you're actually accessing you can do the following:

```
char * dir = getcwd(NULL, 0);   
printf("%s\\Ressources\\Shaders\\texture.vs", dir);
```

Comment: Okay, it got even more strange. First, getcwd is too deprecated, I cant even access it in my windows-application. Also _getcwd doesnt work. But I tried the last thing, and it told me the file exists, but still gives the 0xcccccc error. Now the even more strange thing: If I insert the files in the working directory and in the subfolder, it opens from subfolder path. And even if i have nothing in the subfolder but give him the path, it opens from working directory. As if he just ignores the path.

Comment: Well, Visual Studio doesnt like me sometimes. Now it works. I did not change anything but it works. I guess I should be happy. Thanks.